# TreeList - how to get last child node of the current selected parent node?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, xtratreelist

I have created **TreeList** in Windows form and I added **up and down buttons** .In treelist there are lot of **parent nodes** with **child nodes**. Once expand a parent node , having child nodes and the child node is also a parent node. I want to get the  count value of child node for current selected Parent Node.

Please Guide me solve this issue.

Thanks and regards

Saravanan

Answer (score 1):

The **[`SelectedNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.selectednode(v=vs.110).aspx)** property of a `TreeView` object returns the currently selected node.

For any node in a tree view (including the one returned by `SelectedNode`), the **[`LastNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.lastnode(v=vs.110).aspx)** property returns the last child node under it.

In general, it would be beneficial for you to study all the properties and methods of a class that you're working on, to discover is behaviours. For instance in this case, looking at the [`TreeView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx) class and [`TreeNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode(v=vs.110).aspx) class gives you the information required to navigate a tree view.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance

Comment: @saravanansaravana - you're welcome. If this answer helped, do upvote it/mark it as the chosen answer.

Comment: I don't have so much of reputations..that's why i can't upvote for your answer..while I am clicking upvote it says  "  Ýou have less amount of reputation so you can't."...sorry...But anyway thanks for your guidance

Comment: @saravanansaravana, can you mark this as 'answered'? (This is not 'upvote'. As OP only you can do that.)

Comment: 15 reputation needs to upvote the suggestion.But i have only 8.

Comment: @saravanansaravana - not to worry. You've marked it as answered, that's good enough, to ensure the question doesn't get flagged as a 'still open' one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In my task ,I searched a lot of process.But there is no need to find out the count of child or parents nodes ..there is a predefined function in c#.which is used to move all over the in the treelist nodes.

`TreeList.MoveNextVisible();`

`Treelist.MovePrevVisible();`

or

`TreeList.MoveNext();`

`TreeList.MoveNextVisible();`

or

`TreeList.Move();`

`TreeList.Move();`

Once expand nodes in treelist,these prededined fuction will move in to their parents and its child nodes